# Whats the correct way to use robots.txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, seo, robots.txt

I am trying to get `robots.txt` to work so that search engines start indexing my website and show meta info like descriptions etc.

However, I get this message:

```
A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more.
```

Here is what my **robots.txt** look like.

```
# See http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/norobots.html for documentation on how to use the robots.txt file
#
# To ban all spiders from the entire site uncomment the next two lines:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /tags/*
Disallow: /users/*
```

What do I need to change?

This is a Rails4 application hosted on Heroku and is in the public directory in the Rails repository

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde Not sure what you mean . SEO that requires you to write code and get a web app functioning should be stackoverflow question. In-fact a lot of work with new apps and getting growth would involve growth hacking.

Comment: @JohnConde This question is about robots.txt, targets a specific problem, and is properly tagged. Looks okay to me.

Comment: Asking how a search engine will display/rank/parse your site is off topic

Comment: There is an SEO tag on stackoverflow and it has 4K+ subscribers. Also I did not ask how the search engine will display/rank/parse any website though it should also be a valid question to learn how a search engine does that. May be the wording of the question isn't correct and I will be happy to change it if there are suggestions. I am surprised SEO is being treated as a second grade citizen on SO.

Comment: @codeObserver Did you actually click on the SEO tag and read its contents? I *strongly* recommend that you do.

Comment: You get this message for which URL? And the robots.txt is accessible on which URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is not compulsory to use **robots.txt** file! you only need to use them in case you don't want the search engines to crawl specific pages or directories of your website.

In your case, you are restricting search engines to crawl tags and users' directories hosted on the root. Now, any page inside this directory will give this error.

I also recommend using the Google webmaster tool and verifying your website. You can test Robots.txt file from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing some asterisks:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /tags/
Disallow: /users/
```

Meanwhile, providing a location to your site map might be helpful too:

```
Sitemap: www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Thanks @Vidya for the response. I will try it out. Some of the websites use asterisks https://www.airbnb.com/robots.txt , http://www.quora.com/robots.txt 

Thanks about mentioning sitemap.xml .I will read more about it.